# RNNで文章生成モデルを作る際にたびたび発生する問題について

Tags: 深層学習, 自然言語処理

RNNで文章生成を行うと毎回出力文章の末尾の文字が連続してしまいます。
どのようなモデルを用いた場合でも発生します。

例：**明日は晴れるといいなななななななななな**

のような感じです。

この問題に遭遇した経験がある方、
もしくはこの問題の解決法を知っている方がいらしたら回答いただきたいです。

Comment: これも https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/69247/4715 にコメントした内容で解決しないでしょうか