# PytorchでSeq2seqを設計したが、同じ単語ばかり出力される

Tags: python, 深層学習, 自然言語処理, pytorch

PytorchでSeq2seqを使って文章の校正を行おうとしたのですが、
Decoderから同じ単語しか出力されません。

main.pyです。
これを実行すると訓練などもろもろを実行します。

```
#main.py
import copy
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.optim as optim
import argparse
import sentencepiece as spm

from loader import Seq2seqDataset
from train import Operator

from models.EncoderDecoder import EncoderDecoder, Encoder, Decoder

from models.Decoder import Decoder as attentionGRU
from models.GRU import GRU

sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp.load("./data/index.model")

def make_model(vocab, maxlen, d_model=512):
    "Helper: Construct a model from hyperparameters."
    c = copy.deepcopy
    decoder_gru = attentionGRU(d_model, vocab, d_model, maxlen)
    gru = GRU(d_model, vocab)
    model = EncoderDecoder(Encoder(gru), Decoder(decoder_gru, maxlen))
    return model.cuda()

def data_load(maxlen, source_size, batch_size):
    data_set = Seq2seqDataset(maxlen=maxlen)
    data_num = len(data_set)
    train_ratio = int(data_num*0.8)
    eval_ratio = int(data_num*0.1)
    test_ratio = int(data_num*0.1)
    res = int(data_num - (train_ratio + eval_ratio + test_ratio))
    train_ratio += res
    ratio=[train_ratio, eval_ratio, test_ratio]
    train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(data_set, ratio)
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    del(train_dataset)
    del(data_set)
    return dataloader, val_dataloader

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parse training parameters')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=128,
                        help='number of examples in a batch')
    parser.add_argument('--maxlen', type=int, default=20,
                        help='Sequences will be padded or truncated to this size.')    
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=10,
                        help='the number of epochs to train')   
    parser.add_argument('--hidden_size', type=int, default=512,
                        help='the number of hidden dim')                       
    args = parser.parse_args()             

    vocab = sp.get_piece_size()

    train_loader, val_loader = data_load(args.maxlen, vocab, args.batch_size)
    model = make_model(vocab, args.maxlen, args.hidden_size)
    criterion = nn.NLLLoss(ignore_index=0).cuda()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
    training_operator = Operator(model, optimizer, criterion)
    for epoch in range(args.epochs):
        training_operator.run_epoch(epoch, train_loader, val_loader)
```

train.pyです。
訓練や検証などを行います。

```
#train.py

from utils import to_np, trim_seqs
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import corpus_bleu, SmoothingFunction
import sentencepiece as spm

sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp.load("./data/index.model")

clip = 5.0

class Operator:
    def __init__(self, model, optimizer, criterion):
        self.model = model
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.criterion = criterion

    def run_epoch(self, epoch, train_loader, eval_loader):
        self.model.train()
        losses = []
        sampled_idxs = []
        for idx, data in enumerate(train_loader):
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()

            input_data = Variable(data[0].cuda())
            target = data[1].cuda()
            target_y = Variable(target[:, 1:])
            target = Variable(target[:, :-1])
            
            out, _ = self.model(input_data, target)

            loss = self.loss_compute(out, target_y, True)
            losses.append(to_np(loss))
        train_loss = sum(losses) / len(losses)
        eval_loss, bleuscore = self.evaluate(out, eval_loader)
        print("epochs: {}  train_loss: {}  eval_loss: {}  val_bleuscore: {}".format(epoch+1, train_loss, eval_loss, bleuscore))

    def loss_compute(self, out, target, flag=False):
        loss = self.criterion(out.contiguous().view(-1, out.size(-1)), target.contiguous().view(-1))

        if flag:
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm(self.model.parameters(), clip)
            self.optimizer.step()
        return loss

    def evaluate(self, out, loader):
        self.model.eval()
        losses = []
        all_output_seqs = []
        all_target_seqs = []
        for idx, data in enumerate(loader):
            with torch.no_grad():
                sampled_index = []
                decoder_outputs = []
                sampled_idxs = []
                input_data = data[0].cuda()
                target = data[1].cuda()
                target_y = target[:, 1:]
                _, hidden = self.model.encode(input_data)
                start_symbol = [[sp.PieceToId("<s>")] for i in range(input_data.size(0))]
                decoder_input = torch.tensor(start_symbol).cuda()
                for i in range(input_data.size(1)):
                    decoder_output, hidden = self.model.decode(decoder_input, hidden)
                    _,topi = torch.topk(decoder_output, 1, dim=-1)
                    decoder_outputs.append(decoder_output)
                    sampled_idxs.append(topi)
                    decoder_input = topi.squeeze(1)
                sampled_idxs = torch.stack(sampled_idxs, dim=1)
                decoder_outputs = torch.stack(decoder_outputs, dim=1)
                sampled_idxs = sampled_idxs.squeeze()
                decoder_outputs = decoder_outputs.squeeze()
                loss = self.loss_compute(decoder_outputs, target_y)
                all_output_seqs.extend(trim_seqs(sampled_idxs))
                all_target_seqs.extend([list(seq[seq > 0])] for seq in to_np(target))
                losses.append(to_np(loss))
        bleu_score = corpus_bleu(all_target_seqs, all_output_seqs, smoothing_function=SmoothingFunction().method1)
        mean_loss = sum(losses) / len(losses)
        self.generator(all_output_seqs, all_target_seqs, input_data.size(1))
        return mean_loss, bleu_score

    def generator(self, all_output_seqs, all_target_seqs, maxlen):
        with open("./log/result.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            for sentence in all_output_seqs:
                for tok in sentence:
                    f.write(sp.IdToPiece(int(tok)))
                f.write("\n")

        with open("./log/target.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            for sentence in all_target_seqs:
                for tok in sentence[0]:
                    f.write(sp.IdToPiece(int(tok)))
                f.write("\n")
```

loader.pyです。
コーパスをcsvファイルに格納したものを整形して返します。

```
#loader.py
import torch
import numpy as np
import csv
import sentencepiece as spm

class Seq2seqDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, maxlen):
        self.sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
        self.sp.load("./data/index.model")
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        

        with open('./data/parallel_data.csv', mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        #with open('./data/sample.csv', mode='r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:    
            csv_file = csv.reader(f)
            read_data = [row for row in csv_file]
        self.data_num = len(read_data) - 1
        jp_data = []
        es_data = []
        for i in range(1, self.data_num):    
            jp_data.append(read_data[i][1:2])
            es_data.append(read_data[i][2:3])


        self.en_data_idx = np.zeros((len(jp_data), maxlen))
        self.de_data_idx = np.zeros((len(es_data), maxlen+1))

        for i,sentence in enumerate(jp_data):
            for j,idx in enumerate(self.sp.EncodeAsIds(sentence[0])[0:]):
                self.en_data_idx[i][j] = idx
                if j == maxlen-1:
                    break
            if j < maxlen-1:
                self.en_data_idx[i][j:] = self.sp.PieceToId("<unk>")
            self.en_data_idx[i][-1] = self.sp.PieceToId("</s>")
        for i,sentence in enumerate(es_data):
            self.de_data_idx[i][0] = self.sp.PieceToId("<s>")
            for j,idx in enumerate(self.sp.EncodeAsIds(sentence[0])[0:]):
                self.de_data_idx[i][j+1] = idx
                if j+1 == maxlen:
                    break
            if j+1 < maxlen:
                self.de_data_idx[i][j+1:] = self.sp.PieceToId("<unk>")
            self.de_data_idx[i][-1] = self.sp.PieceToId("</s>")
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.data_num

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        en_data = torch.tensor(self.en_data_idx[idx-1][:], dtype=torch.long)
        de_data = torch.tensor(self.de_data_idx[idx-1][:], dtype=torch.long)
        target = torch.zeros((self.maxlen+1), dtype=torch.long)
        for i, data in enumerate(de_data[:]):
            target[i] = data
        target[0] = self.sp.PieceToId("<s>")

        return en_data, target
```

GRU.py
エンコーダです。

```
#GRU.py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class GRU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers=1):
        super(GRU, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(self.output_size, self.hidden_size, padding_idx=0)
        self.embedding.weight.data.normal_(0, 1 / self.hidden_size**0.5)
        self.embedding.weight.data[0, :] = 0.0
        self.gru_source = nn.GRU(hidden_size, hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers,
                                bidirectional=True, batch_first=True, dropout=0.2)

    def forward(self, sentence_words):
        self.gru_source.flatten_parameters()
        embedded = self.embedding(sentence_words)
        hx = self.init_hidden(sentence_words.size(0))
        encoder_output, hx = self.gru_source(embedded, hx)
        encoder_output = (encoder_output[:,:,:self.hidden_size] + encoder_output[:,:,self.hidden_size:]) / 2
        hx = (hx[0] + hx[1]) / 2 
        hx = hx.unsqueeze(0)
        return encoder_output, hx

    def init_hidden(self, bc):
        hx = torch.zeros((self.num_layers*2, bc, self.hidden_size))
        hx = hx.cuda()
        return hx
```

Decoder.pyです。
デコーダです。

```
#Decoder.py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim, vocab_size, embedding_dim, max_length):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, padding_idx=0)
        self.gru = nn.GRU(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, batch_first=True)
        self.hidden2linear = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, vocab_size)
        
    def forward(self, sequence, encoder_state):
        embedding = self.word_embeddings(sequence)
        embedding = F.relu(embedding)
        output, state = self.gru(embedding, encoder_state)
        output = self.hidden2linear(output)
        output = F.log_softmax(output, dim=-1)
        return output, state
```

EncoderDecoder.pyです。
EncoderとDecoderをひとまとめにして処理しやすくしています。

```
#EncoderDecoder.py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable

class EncoderDecoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder):
        super(EncoderDecoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def forward(self, data, target):
        out, hx = self.encoder(data)
        return self.decoder(target, hx)
    def decode(self, target, hx):
        return self.decoder(target, hx)
    def encode(self, input_data):
        return self.encoder(input_data)

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, base_module):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.base_module = base_module

    def forward(self, data):
        return self.base_module(data)

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, base_module, maxlen):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.base_module = base_module
        self.maxlen = maxlen

    def forward(self, data, hx):
        return self.base_module(data, hx)
```

これを訓練して文章を生成すると、
全てpadで構成された文章になります。
lossも問題なく減少していきますが、生成される文章は×です。

以下出力例です。

```
epochs: 1  train_loss: 6.804564086012185  eval_loss: 6.8490905404090885  val_bleuscore: 0.00021425393895175578
epochs: 2  train_loss: 6.16480832815932  eval_loss: 7.3809502720832825  val_bleuscore: 5.9522479993669076e-05
epochs: 3  train_loss: 5.995282799291154  eval_loss: 7.583597528934479  val_bleuscore: 6.663744208921663e-05
epochs: 4  train_loss: 5.8298093747026245  eval_loss: 7.464733970165253  val_bleuscore: 0.00021450632944840199
epochs: 5  train_loss: 5.752497753777062  eval_loss: 7.193604528903961  val_bleuscore: 0.00013741750714360893
```

問題点などを教えていただけると幸いです。
個人的には、EncoderDecoderを統合して扱っているところ、modelをselfで渡して訓練しているところなどが問題になのではないかと思っています。
見ていただけるのであればすべてのファイルを共有します。

Answer (score 1):

同じようなことを試そうとしています。

以下の論文にseq2seqで作ったモデルに制約をかけ、繰り返し単語が出力されることを防ぐ仕組みが記載されています。

[Sparse and Constrained Attention for Neural Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.08241v1)

有志による論文の要旨
https://github.com/ymym3412/acl-papers/issues/218

> 通常のattentionではどの時刻tでも全ての単語に少なからずweightを与えてしまい、decode時のrepititionを引き起こしてしまう。そこでattentionのweightがsparseになるsparsemaxに、attentionをかける単語数/回数に制約をかけるconstrained softmaxを組み合わせたconstrained sparsemaxを提案